# Charge density of line of length $L$ expressed with Dirac delta function in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: electrostatics, charge, density, dirac-delta-distributions

I want to find the charge density of a line charge of length $L$ in cylindrical coordinates.
I suppose charge density is independent of $\phi$. The line charge is only defined for coordinates of $z$ between $L/2$ and $-L/2$. So I suppose we can express the charge density as:

$$\rho(r,\phi,z)=f(r,z)\delta(r)\theta(L/2-|z|)$$

I want to find $f(r,z)$, so I can try to use the volume integral to find it. However, something must be wrong in my definition, as this integral integrates to zero:
$$Q=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \int^{2\pi}_{0} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(r,z)\delta(r)\theta(L/2-|z|)~r~dz~d\phi~dr\\=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \int^{2\pi}_{0} f(r,z)\theta(L/2-|z|)~0~dz~d\phi=0$$

I can't find my mistake, and I would really appreciate your help.

By the way, I already know that $\rho=\frac{Q}{L}$, but I want to prove it with the cylindrical coordinates and delta function that I mentioned.

$\theta$ is the step function.

Comment: Probably relevant https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398777/dirac-delta-in-polar-coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compensate for the $r$ in the volume element
$r\ dr\ d\phi\ dz$ you need a factor $\frac{1}{r}$ in
your charge density $\rho$.
And the over-all constant is adjusted so that the total
volume integral will be $Q$. You finally get
$$\rho(r,\phi,z)=\frac{Q}{2\pi rL}\delta(r)\theta(L/2-|z|)$$

The term $\frac{1}{2\pi r}\delta(r)$ might seem weird at first,
but it is actually equal to $\delta(x)\delta(y)$.
See also the math question *[Dirac delta in polar coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398777/dirac-delta-in-polar-coordinates)*
and its accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks! However, there is something that is not yet clear to me. For the case of a uniformly charged sphere, we would have to use the correction factor of $\frac{1}{r^2 sin\theta}$ But, when we calculate the charge density, we would get: $\rho=\frac{Q\delta(r-R)}{2\pi ^2 r^2 sin \theta}$. This wouldn't seem to be the right answer.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. My concept of $\delta$ and the correction term was not quite good. The following site can help others when trying to understand the definition of the dirac delta function in curvilinear coordinates when there is some kind of symmetry. [link](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~ercelebi/mp03.pdf)